# how to check if getwriter or getoutputstream is already used when called inside a servlet file

Tags: java, servlets

I need to write append to the response a hidden tag after the server is done generating the jsp response. I keep getting the illegalstate exception. So I used getWriter instead of getOutputStream now its complaining of this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: strict servlet API: cannot call getWriter() after getOutputStream()
```

I am overriding getWriter in a response wrapper which I pass down the chain in my filter

on return from that method I append stuff with write

Since I am getting errors on using either one of getWriter or `getOutputStream`, I assume I have to check somehow which of these has already been used.

Answer (score 2):

> Since I am getting errors on using either one of getWriter or getOutputStream, I assume I have to check somehow which of these has already been used.

There is no standard way to do that.

If you are going to implement this using a custom wrapper, then the wrapper itself needs to keep track of whether `getWriter` or `getOutputStream` has been called.  You could expose this state by adding an extra public method to your wrapper implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the response headers or data after its been generated with a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). Its a little bit of work to implement one the first time, but once you've done it its not that bad and they're quite powerful.